# Sqlite Update multiple value with single where clause

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to update two columns "ORDER_NetTotal" which is of type TEXT and "ORDER_TOTAL_QTY" which is of type INTEGER with a where condition on "DBHelper.ORDER_CONFIRM_MASTER_ID" which is primary key. The problem is that "ORDER_TOTAL_QTY" gets updated while "ORDER_NetTotal" does not get updated with update query. below is my code.

```
 public int updateOrderQtyMaster(int deliveryId, int newQty, Float newTotalAmount) {

    Log.d("updateParameter : ", newQty + "    " + newTotalAmount);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_NetTotal, String.valueOf(newTotalAmount));
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_TOTAL_QTY, newQty);
    Log.d("updateDelivery", values.toString());
    try {
        return db.update(DBHelper.TBL_ORDER_CONFIRM_MASTER, values, DBHelper.ORDER_CONFIRM_MASTER_ID + " = " + deliveryId, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utility.logCatMsg("Exception in updateOrderQtyMaster Method in SQLite: " + e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
db.update(DBHelper.TBL_ORDER_CONFIRM_MASTER, values, DBHelper.ORDER_CONFIRM_MASTER_ID + "=?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(deliveryId)});
```

Comment: first i have tried this but same result....the DBHelper.ORDER_NetTotal is not updated

Comment: Please post your log. What values your are get in deliveryId, newQty and newTotalAmount? Do you get any error releated to database in logcat?

Comment: 03-19 11:14:13.043 23275-23275/detrack.zaryansgroup.com.detrack D/updateParameter :: 3    75.0
03-19 11:14:13.043 23275-23275/detrack.zaryansgroup.com.detrack D/updateDelivery: TotalQuantity=3 NetTotal=75
03-19 11:14:13.043 23275-23275/detrack.zaryansgroup.com.detrack D/masterQtyUpdated :: true
03-19 11:14:13.053 23275-23275/detrack.zaryansgroup.com.detrack D/zeddelivery: TblOrderConfirmMaster updated..

Comment: deliveryId?? Value

Comment: sir deliveryId is working properly because if there is any issue with deliveryId, the TotalQuantity column will not be updated

Answer (score 0):

make some change like newTotalAmount is containing real number there for is not directly convert in string there for you nettotal is not update used below code then check it.

```
String.valueOf(Math.round(newTotalAmount))
```